# Book and course recommendations - sister sites to direct them to?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Inspired by [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/127733/61443).

We get a lot of questions for the following patterns:

> I want to get into security / some sub-branch of security. What books or courses should I read / take?

These get closed as off-topic - and rightly so since their answers would quickly get outdated. That said, they are still good questions, and there must be somewhere on the internet where they are welcome. Reddit often gets mentioned, for example, but not being a member of any of the other online security communities, I don't want to naively send these askers off to become a problem there too.

**Question: Do you know of any sites that would welcome these kinds of questions that we can use as a standard "off-topic here, but go ask [here] instead?"**

Or, put a different way:

**What sister sites does Security.SE have that are more liberal about discussing quickly outdated / opinionated topics?**

Comment: Sounds like an interesting proposal for Area51: "where can I learn ...?"

Comment: There's alread a "Book Recommendations" on Area51.

Answer (score 4):

Part of the problem is that most questions in that pattern are too broad to be able to point them to anywhere useful. If narrow enough, then the answers are pretty evident (or even answerable).

For example, in the cited case, www.corelan.be would be a great place for them to start. But what about someone wanting to learn the topics in the CCNA body of knowledge?

And that's the problem: we'd need to maintain a list of places where people could go to learn specific things. We could do that in the wiki or a blog post, if we want to take on maintaining that.